# How to write this Logic in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'd like to know how to write this line bellow in DAX. I'm a beginner and I'm having a lot of problems trying to write this code in Dax to return the value I need.

```
(select 
top 1 Payor.CompanyName 
from Payor, PatientPayor 
where PatientPayor.PatientSer = pat.PatientSer
and Payor.PayorSer = PatientPayor.PayorSer) as conv,
```

This is what I tried to do so far.

```
Convenio =
TOPN ( 1, VALUES ( Payor[CompanyName] ), PatientPayor[PatientSer] )
    = FILTER ( Patient, PatientPayor[PatientSer] = Patient[PatientSer] )
```

Comment: Can you share your sample data?

Comment: I'm connected to a SQL Server Database and I've been wondering if creating Temp Tables with the data I want to show in PBI would be the best way to solve my issues with DAX. What do you think @AngeloCanepa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve it with the code bellow:

formula =
VAR currpayorSer =
SELECTEDVALUE ( PatientPayor[PayorSer] )
VAR currPatientSer =
SELECTEDVALUE ( PatientPayor[PatientSer] )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
MIN ( Payor[CompanyName] ),
FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Payor ), Payor[PayorSer] = currpayorSer ),
FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Patient ), Patient[PatientSer] = currPatientSer )
)

Comment: Please format the code